# Change text size in TextView for differents types of device screens

Tags: android, textview, size

I need to change the text size for differents types of device screens.
I use this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics;
metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float Textsize =txt_pri.getTextSize()/metrics.density; 
txt_pri.setTextSize(Textsize);
```

This works well on a samsung s3, but does not work on a tablet.

Comment: The title of your question states that you want to resize a TextView, in the description you're saying that you need to resize an ImageView, and your code is actually making calculations on the text size. So what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, you should achieve this in the XML using a RelativeLayout (which you can also create in code) and setting the android:alignParentLeft/Right attributes and android:layout_marginLeft/Right attributes.

Comment: Take a look on [Screens Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to support multiple screen easily

Comment: i need that the imageview increases or decreases in any way automatically.

Comment: why do you want to resize text when the screen has different density in the first place? Maybe _dip_ (density independent pixels) is what you are looking for? see explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) Well for fonts you should better just use _sp_